# Not being able to POST in MEAN single page app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have only just started trying out NodeJS. Having a little experience with Angular, I thought of trying out a MEAN stack to-do app tutorial from [scotch](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular).

I understand what is happening and how angular, node and my view are supposed to be working together. But they just aren't. I've made sure not to miss anything. Here is my code.

Server.js is in the root folder

```
// server.js

// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

// configuration =================

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/uwa8sIje');     // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

// creating mongoose model ================================

var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text: String
});

// Todo is the mongo db. Creating API for CRUD in the db
//============================================================


app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    Todo.find(function (err, todos) {       //within 'get' we are looking for all the entries in the db 
        if(err) {
            res.send(err)                   //checking for errors
        }
        res.json(todos);                    //response sends all listed todos in JSON 
    })
})

app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) { //to post a new todo

    Todo.create({                           //creating a new post. information comes from AJAX request from Angular
        text: req.body.text,
        done: false
    }, function(err, todo) {                //checking errors
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        Todo.find(function (err, todos) {   //after post is added, find and display all existing todos again
            if(err) {
                res.send(err)
            }
            res.json(todos);
        })

    })

})

app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {  //delete a todo

    Todo.remove({                                       //remove a todo from database
        _id: req.params.todo_id,                        //todo id to be removed is provided by the request url(params)
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        }


        Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
         if (err) {
            res.send(err)
            }
            res.json(todos);
        })
    })
})

//======================================================================



app.get('*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html')                 //load this single view file. angular will handle the 
                                                        //page changes on the front end
})


// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

My angular controller lies in the public folder along with my view

```
var Todoz = angular.module('Todoz', []);

function mainController($http, $scope) {

    $scope.formData = {};

    $http.get('/api/todos')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
            console.log(data);
        })

    $scope.createTodo = function() {

        $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.todos = data;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log('Error' + data)
            })
    }

    $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {

        $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
    };

Todoz.controller("mainController", mainController);

}
```

**and my minimal view**

```
<head>
    <title>
        To-Do-and-Node-To-Do
    </title>
</head>
<body ng-app="Todoz">

<h1>The To-do-ist</h1>

<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="formData.text"></input>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="createTodo()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./core.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I start the server with 'nodemon server.js' my console logs a /GET request and the app shows on my port 8080. However when I try to post a new item from my text-box and expect it to console.log, it doesn't do anything. My browser console returns this

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/todos net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED        angular.js:8632
Error core.js:23
POST http://localhost:8080/api/todos net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED        angular.js:8632
Error core.js:23
```

Please help. I have no clue what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you please check *request url*, *request payload* on browser dev tools. what is the status code are you getting.

Comment: @PalakBhansali Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/todos

Request Payload : {text : "inputtext"};

Comment: I am sorry for late reply.did you sort this out ? what is the status code you are getting for your request.

Comment: Having the exact same issue and curious if you ever found the root cause for this?